# Kotlin - cast to Class<T> or to KClass<T>

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I can cast `Any` to another type like so

```
val obj: Any = 123
val num: Int = obj as Int
```

In my case I want to be able to either cast to `Class<Int>` or `KClass<Int>`, something like...

```
val obj: Any = 123
val kotlinClass = Int::class
val javaClass = Int::class.java

val num : Int = obj.castTo(kotlinClass)
val num2: Int = obj.castTo(javaClass)
```

How exactly can this be achieved?

Comment: [KClass.cast](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/cast.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it the other way around, i.e. using the class to cast the object:

```
val num : Int = kotlinClass.cast(obj)
val num2 : Int = javaClass.cast(obj)
```

Be sure to add `kotlin-reflect` as a library, if you really require [`KClass.cast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/cast.html).
Alternatively you may also be interested in [`KClass.safeCast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/safe-cast.html).